# how to make a loop over myoverlay items

Tags: android

how can i make a loop for my overlay items android !! and what if i want to remove one of them by using  mapView.getOverlays().remove(p); !! its doesn't work why ?? here is the code

```
enter code here
public void addOverLays(){
String [] coordinates = {"31.216487288475037","29.932637214660645" ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
double lat = 30.084686279296875,lat2 = 51.5002,lat3=29.987091422080994;
double log = 31.33642494678493, log2 = -0.1262,log3=31.43909454345703;

p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));
p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);

itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");

itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
mc.setZoom(17); 
 mc.animateTo(p);
```

}

Comment: Add your overlay items into an ArrayList and then loop through it

Answer (score 0):

Adding overlays does work in your code - if you mean you don't see any changes, then you have to call MapView.invalidate() to have it re-draw itself with the newly added overlays. The same is true when you remove an overlay.