# cant Remove overlay items?

Tags: android

i want to remove an added Overlay item from my mapview ,here we go with the code  but it didnt remove the over lay item why this ?

```
enter code here

public void addOverLays(){
String [] coordinates = {"31.216487288475037","29.932637214660645" ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
double lat = 30.084686279296875,lat2 = 29.987107515335083,lat3=29.987091422080994;
double log = 31.33642494678493, log2 =  31.43912136554718,log3=31.43909454345703;

p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));
p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dotred);
drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);

itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");

itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
mc.setZoom(17); 
mc.animateTo(p1);


 mapView.getOverlays().remove(p);
  mapView.invalidate();
       }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851437/how-to-make-a-loop-over-myoverlay-items. During the last few days you have asked the same questions again and again under identities 'fofo', jojo' and now 'koko'. You haven't accepted any perfectly good answers given to you under these identities. This is not the way to seek help on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove the overlay item, not the geopoint:

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(itemizedOverlay);
```